# Can't Serialize Custom Types

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xsd

I'm trying to extend the `UserArea` in the hr-xml type `ProcessOrganizationChartDataAreaType` 
I defined type `OrganizationChartUserArea` that inherits from `UserAreaType1`

```
[XmlType]
    public class OrganizationChartUserArea :UserAreaType1
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public HcrChoiceSet DefaultChoicesSet { get; set; }

        [XmlElement]
        public HcrChoiceSet CurrentChoicesSet { get; set; }
    }
```

this also uses a custom type HcrChoiceSet

```
 [XmlType]
    public class HcrChoiceSet
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public FreeFormEffectivePeriodType OngoingMeasurementPeriod { get; set; }

        [XmlElement]
        public FreeFormEffectivePeriodType OngoingStabilityPeriod { get; set; }

        [XmlElement]
        public FreeFormEffectivePeriodType OngoingAdministrationPeriod { get; set; }
    }
```

when i try to searlize an instance of this extended class

```
 [TestMethod]
        public void SerializeOrganizationChart()
        {
            var organizationSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProcessOrganizationChartType));
            var organizationWriter = new XmlTextWriter("C:\\ProcessOrganizationChart.xml", new UTF8Encoding());

            var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            namespaces.Add("", "http://www.hr-xml.org/3");
            namespaces.Add("oa", "http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9");
            namespaces.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            namespaces.Add("schemaLocation", "http://www.hr-xml.org/3  ../Developer/BODs/ProcessOrganizationChart.xsd");

            organizationSerializer.Serialize(organizationWriter, processOrganizationChart, namespaces);

            Assert.Inconclusive("This is not a true unit test.");
        }
```

I get an error saying

> Test method
>   SomeNamespace.Tests.OrganizationChartTest.SerializeOrganizationChart
>   threw exception:  System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error
>   generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   The type SomeNamespace.Tests.OrganizationChartUserArea was not
>   expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types
>   that are not known statically.

How can I resolve this?

```
 [TestInitialize]
        public void InitTest()
        {
            processOrganizationChart = new ProcessOrganizationChartType
                {
                    ApplicationArea = new ApplicationAreaType
                        {
                            CreationDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                            BODID = new IdentifierType1 {Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()},
                        },
                    DataArea = new ProcessOrganizationChartDataAreaType
                        {
                            Process = new ProcessType
                                {
                                    ActionCriteria = new[]
                                        {
                                            new ActionCriteriaType
                                                {
                                                    ActionExpression = new[]
                                                        {
                                                            new ActionExpressionType
                                                                {
                                                                    actionCode = "Add",
                                                                    Value =
                                                                        "/ProcessOrganizationChart/DataArea/OrganizationChart"
                                                                }
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        }
                                },
                            OrganizationChart = new[]
                                {
                                    new OrganizationChartType
                                        {
                                            OrganizationUnit = new[]
                                                {
                                                    new OrgChartOrganizationUnitType
                                                        {
                                                            validFrom = "2013-01-01",
                                                            OrganizationUnitID = new IdentifierType2
                                                                {
                                                                    Value = "901"
                                                                },
                                                            ParentOrganizationUnit = new ParentOrganizationUnitType
                                                                {
                                                                    OrganizationUnitID = new IdentifierType2
                                                                        {
                                                                            Value = "900"
                                                                        }
                                                                },
                                                            RelatedOrganizationUnit = new[]
                                                                {
                                                                    new RelatedOrganizationUnitType
                                                                        {
                                                                            OrganizationUnitID = new IdentifierType2
                                                                                {
                                                                                    Value = "900"
                                                                                }
                                                                        }
                                                                },
                                                            OrganizationUnitName = new OrganizationNameType
                                                                {
                                                                    languageID = "en-US",
                                                                    Value = "SomeCompany"
                                                                },
                                                            TypeCode = new[]
                                                                {
                                                                    new CodeType1
                                                                        {
                                                                            listID = "ClientStatus",
                                                                            Value = "Active"
                                                                        },
                                                                    new CodeType1
                                                                        {
                                                                            listID = "ALEIndicator",
                                                                            Value = "True"
                                                                        },
                                                                    new CodeType1
                                                                        {
                                                                            listID = "EducationIndicator",
                                                                            Value = "False"
                                                                        },
                                                                    new CodeType1
                                                                        {
                                                                            listID = "MedicalBenefitsOffered",
                                                                            Value = "False",
                                                                        },
                                                                    new CodeType1
                                                                        {
                                                                            listID = "MedicalBenefitsStatusDate",
                                                                            Value = "2013-01-01"
                                                                        }
                                                                }
                                                            ,
                                                            UserArea = new OrganizationChartUserArea
                                                                {
                                                                    DefaultChoicesSet = new HcrChoiceSet
                                                                        {
                                                                            OngoingAdministrationPeriod
                                                                                = new FreeFormEffectivePeriodType
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        StartDate = new FreeFormDateType
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                FormattedDateTime =
                                                                                                    "2015-01-01"
                                                                                            },
                                                                                        EndDate = new FreeFormDateType
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                FormattedDateTime =
                                                                                                    "2015-01-31"
                                                                                            },
                                                                                        Duration = "P1M"
                                                                                    },
                                                                            OngoingMeasurementPeriod =
                                                                                new FreeFormEffectivePeriodType
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        StartDate = new FreeFormDateType
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                FormattedDateTime =
                                                                                                    "2014-01-01"
                                                                                            },
                                                                                        EndDate = new FreeFormDateType
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                FormattedDateTime =
                                                                                                    "2014-12-31"
                                                                                            },
                                                                                        Duration = "P12M"
                                                                                    },
                                                                            OngoingStabilityPeriod =
                                                                                new FreeFormEffectivePeriodType
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        StartDate = new FreeFormDateType
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                FormattedDateTime =
                                                                                                    "2015-01-01"
                                                                                            },
                                                                                        EndDate = new FreeFormDateType
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                FormattedDateTime =
                                                                                                    "2015-12-31"
                                                                                            },
                                                                                        Duration = "P12M"
                                                                                    }

                                                                        },
                                                                    CurrentChoicesSet = new HcrChoiceSet
                                                                        {
                                                                            OngoingAdministrationPeriod
                                                                                = new FreeFormEffectivePeriodType
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        StartDate = new FreeFormDateType
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                FormattedDateTime =
                                                                                                    "2015-01-01"
                                                                                            },
                                                                                        EndDate = new FreeFormDateType
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                FormattedDateTime =
                                                                                                    "2015-01-31"
                                                                                            }
                                                                                    },
                                                                            OngoingMeasurementPeriod =
                                                                                new FreeFormEffectivePeriodType
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        StartDate = new FreeFormDateType
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                FormattedDateTime =
                                                                                                    "2014-01-01"
                                                                                            },
                                                                                        EndDate = new FreeFormDateType
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                FormattedDateTime =
                                                                                                    "2014-12-31"
                                                                                            }
                                                                                    },
                                                                            OngoingStabilityPeriod =
                                                                                new FreeFormEffectivePeriodType
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        StartDate = new FreeFormDateType
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                FormattedDateTime =
                                                                                                    "2015-01-01"
                                                                                            },
                                                                                        EndDate = new FreeFormDateType
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                FormattedDateTime =
                                                                                                    "2015-12-31"
                                                                                            }
                                                                                    }

                                                                        }
                                                                }
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                };
        }
```

OrgChartUnitType

```
namespace HrXml.v3_2_1.Types.HrXml
{
    [Serializable]
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    [DesignerCategory("code")]
    [GeneratedCode("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
    [XmlRoot("OrganizationUnit", Namespace = "http://www.hr-xml.org/3", IsNullable = false)]
    [XmlType(Namespace = "http://www.hr-xml.org/3")]
    public class OrgChartOrganizationUnitType
    {
        public OrgChartOrganizationUnitType();

        [XmlElement("AdditionalItem")]
        public AdditionalItemType[] AdditionalItem { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("MemberPosition")]
        public MemberPositionType[] MemberPosition { get; set; }
        public CodeType1 OrganizationLevelCode { get; set; }
        public IdentifierType2 OrganizationUnitID { get; set; }
        public TextType1 OrganizationUnitName { get; set; }
        public ParentOrganizationUnitType ParentOrganizationUnit { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("RelatedOrganizationUnit")]
        public RelatedOrganizationUnitType[] RelatedOrganizationUnit { get; set; }
        [XmlIgnore]
        public AdditionalItemType SingleAdditionalItem { get; set; }
        [XmlIgnore]
        public MemberPositionType SingleMemberPosition { get; set; }
        [XmlIgnore]
        public RelatedOrganizationUnitType SingleRelatedOrganizationUnit { get; set; }
        [XmlIgnore]
        public CodeType1 SingleTypeCode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("TypeCode")]
        public CodeType1[] TypeCode { get; set; }
        public UserAreaType1 UserArea { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string validFrom { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string validTo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to serialize (say how you are using the `XmlSerializer`? Most likely you serialize/deserialize some base type, but you need to include all known subclasses you expect to have (such as the `OrganizationChartUserArea`) EDIT: Also, if `OrganizationChartUserArea` isn't the object you are directly serializing/deserializing, if it is actually a property of a higher-level class that you are serializing, maybe post that as well.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I've added it above

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I have no problem serializing  ProcessOrganizationChartType, its only when I try to extend use my new types. ProcessOrganizationChartType is defined by hr-xml you can see it here http://neptune.pilotfish-net.com/HRXML/index.html?page=http://neptune.pilotfish-net.com/HRXML/model/Format.ProcessOrganizationChart.DataArea.html

Comment: Any reason why you are trying to serialize a `ProcessOrganizationChartType` but posted the code for `OrganizationChartUserArea`? Can you post `ProcessOrganizationChartType`, or are you _also_ trying to serialize an instance of `OrganizationChartUserArea` using the _exact_ serialization code you posted above (_exact_ as in instantiating an `XmlSerializer(typeof(ProcessOrganizationChartType))`)?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I've added more code that make it more clear for you.

Comment: Can you post the `OrgChartOrganizationUnitType` class? I think that's the one that has the `UserArea` property. (if it isn't, please post the class that does have it) EDIT: Sorry for all the requests, but I think this is necessary to give you an exact solution to your problem.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair `OrgChartOrganizationUnitType` is posted now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do not have access to the class to modify and add `XmlInclude` attributes, instead inform the `XmlSerializer` of additional known types to expect to serialize using the [`new XmlSerializer(Type, Type[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5aakyae.aspx) constructor overload:

```
var organizationSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProcessOrganizationChartType), new[]{typeof(OrganizationChartUserArea)});
```

This instructs the `XmlSerializer` to expect and generate serialization information for your custom subclass. Normally the `XmlSerializer` just looks at the types as defined at compile-time on the classes serialized. In this case, `OrgChartOrganizationUnitType` specifies a type of `UserAreaType1` so only that *specific* class is expected and generates serialization information. By telling the `XmlSerializer` to *also* expect `OrganizationChartUserArea` it should hopefully not fail when it is passed an object of that type.

Answer (score 2):

Use XmlInclude attribute in your base class:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(OrganizationChartUserArea))]
class public UserAreaType1
{
 [...]
```

Comment: This is not a class I have access too, I am referencing a dll